# HTTPS error on deployed React project

Tags: reactjs, api, giphy-api

I was trying to host my React project on GH Pages. The deploy worked fine but when I try to search for gifs I get the following error

```
http_browser.js:47 Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://pimmesz.github.io/react-giphy/' was loaded over HTTPS, but 
 requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search? 
q=h&limit=10&rating=g&api_key=MYAPIKEY'. This request has been blocked; the 
content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It seems like the Giphy API is making a `http` request instead of `https`. Is there a way to change the default url which the API uses?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import giphy from 'giphy-api';

import Search from './search.jsx';
import Gif from './gif.jsx';
import GifList from './gif_list.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      gifs: [],
      gif: "xBoysJgwhLEZtAjbY1"
    }
  }

  search = (query) => {
    giphy('APIKEY').search({
      q: query,
      limit: 10,
      rating: 'g'
    }, (err, res) => {
      this.setState({gifs: res.data})
    });
  }

  select = (id) => {
    this.setState({gif: id})
  }


  render() {
    const gifs = this.state.gifs;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="left-scene">
          <Search search={this.search}/>
          <Gif id={this.state.gif} select={this.select}  />
        </div>
        <div className="right-scene">
          <GifList gifs={gifs} select={this.select} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @Pimmesz, the error says that the request comes from your app, so you should check your request url path and change http to https, could you share your gh link?

Comment: Thanks Vito! I've looked through the app but all the requests I make are https...

Link to repo
https://github.com/pimmesz/react-giphy

Link to gh pages live version
https://pimmesz.github.io/react-giphy/

Comment: I found the following in the `index.js` in the `giphy-api` located inside my `node-module`. So by default it is making a http request instead of https. I however have no idea how to change this so that it is used by the Giphy API used in my project...
`/**
* @param options {String|Object} - 
*   options.https {Boolean} - Whether to utilize HTTPS library for requests or HTTP. Defaults to HTTP.
*/`

Comment: Ok seems that the base url of the API uses http, I saw that you're usin giphy-api in the search function the only thing that occurs to me, is to make the request manually to the API end point as you did in you gif.js file in order to not to use node_modules. P.S  I've never work with this API but hope this advice could helps. Nice code.

Comment: Thanks Vito! That worked!!

Live version
https://pimmesz.github.io/react-giphy/

Repo
https://github.com/pimmesz/react-giphy/blob/master/src/components/app.jsx

Answer (score 1):

Changed the giphy API execution to

```
const url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${query}&limit=10&rating=g&api_key=MY_API_KEY`
      fetch(url)
      .then(results => { return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
        this.setState({gifs: data.data});
      });
```

**EDIT**

Found another way!

Setting https to true can be done as an option in the giphy api call

`giphy({ apiKey: "MY_API_KEY", https: true })`